# Building project using ANT that contains droidText.jar

Tags: ant, build, android-droidtext

I have an Android Project which uses droidText Library.
when I run the project using Eclipse Plugin, build well done.
However when I run it using ANT, the build faild and I got this error:

Pre-Dexing /droidText.0.4.jar -> droidText.0.4-39f8a99da14902e4ed96cdcc8f277d6e.jar
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build

I'm prety sure that the problem is related to Android dependency and that's du to uses of duplicated classes in JAR file.
But I don't know how to fix that.
can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The bug was related to the ANT version, before I had ant 1.7 but after I updated the it with ant 1.8.4. things went ok.